# Why does echo dot audio play through my laptop after bluetooth pairing?

Tags: bluetooth

I am trying to use echo dot as a bluetooth speaker for my laptop (Fujitsu Lifebook - win7). In the bluetooth devices windows on the laptop I can see and pair with the echo dot, but after pairing I can hear Alexa through the laptop speaker which is the opposite of what I want. How do I define echo dot as the speaker for the laptop instead of the laptop as the speaker for the echo dot?

Answer (score 5):

My guess is that you paired the device to the computer, instead of vice versa.

Did you:

1. Go into the Alexa app.
2. Go to Settings.
3. Go into Device Settings.
4. Select which echo (if more than one)
5. Click on Bluetooth Devices
6. Select Pair a New Device
7. Open Bluetooth Settings on the computer and pair with the Dot.

If not, try those steps.  If you connected directly to the computer via the app/using voice commands to the computer, it detected it as a speaker.